# How to display count of y or mean of y using gvisBarChart

Tags: r, rstudio

i have the code as below and trying to plot gvisBarChart using the data selected from the drop down. the Server.r and ui.r code is given below

```
#server.r

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

 output$ShowdataColDropDown <- renderUI({
   df <-filedata()
   if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
   #Let's only show numeric columns
   nums <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
   numitems=names(nums[nums])
   selectizeInput("VarData", "Select Data:",c("", numitems()),  multiple=TRUE, options = list(maxItems = 2,placeholder = 'select x and y  parameters'))
   })

  output$ShowdataCatDropDown <- renderUI({
    df <-filedata()
    #Let's only show numeric columns
    nums <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
    numitems=names(nums[nums])
    names(numitems)=numitems
    selectInput("charData", "Select Data:",c("", numitems), selected=numitems[1]) 
    })

output$myplot<-renderGvis({
   #data
   filedata <- data.frame(product=c("A","A","A","B","B"),Sales= c(10,3,4,2,20))

   dfall<-data.frame(cbind(filedata[input$VarData],filedata[input$charData]))

  #input$VarData is the input selected by the user for say 'sales'
  #input$charDatais the input selected by the user for say 'product'


  #The barchart code below is not working; Getting the error as: arguments must      have same length
   gvisBarChart(aggregate(dfall, list(dfall[input$charData]),mean))

    })
  }

#UI.r

 shinyUI(
   fluidPage(
   uiOutput("ShowdataColDropDown"),
   uiOutput("ShowdataCatDropDown"),
   htmloutput("myplot")
  )
```

please help me to dusplay the chart using mean(sales) by product.

Comment: `library(googleVis); plot(gvisBarChart(aggregate(Sales~product, data.frame(product, Sales), mean), yvar = "Sales", options = list(title = "mean")))` for the mean. You can use `sum` instead of `mean` to get the sum, or `length` to get the count.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. but how to use dynamic column name here.

Comment: By specifying a variable containing the name instead of a string?

Comment: #to retrive file data
filedata <- reactive({
    read.csv("C:\\dk.csv",sep=",")
  })

#Data Col as part of the CSV file: product,sales

dfall<-data.frame(cbind(filedata()[input$VarData],filedata()[input$charData]))

#input$VarData is the input selected by the user for say 'sales'
#input$charDatais the input selected by the user for say 'product'


# By barchart code below is not working; Getting the error as: arguments must have same length
gvisBarChart(aggregate(dfall, list(dfall[input$charData]),mean))

Comment: no i think. pls let me know if any more details required.

Comment: edited the original query. pls help

Comment: Thank you. I'd try `gvisBarChart(setNames(aggregate(dfall[, input$VarData], list(dfall[, input$charData]), mean), c(input$charData, input$VarData)), yvar = input$VarData)`.

Comment: Excellant. This helps.

Comment: one more question, can i use this code to generate for columns chart                      gviscolumnChart(setNames(aggregate(dfall[, input$VarData], list(dfall[, input$charData]), mean), c(input$charData, input$VarData)), yvar = input$VarData)

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: i want to use column chart instead of barchar using the same script given by you above on jul 23 @ 11.45

Comment: pls let me know if need more clarity

Comment: I think you should post a new question with a short, reproducible example and abstract from shiny to get more answers.